# How to know if I have this signals in my area?

Tags: signal

How to know if I have this signals in my area?

GSM, GPRS, EDGE, 3G, 4G, HSDPA, HSPA+ and LTE

I don't have any smartphone but I have a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacting your carrier might be best but I stumbled across this site which might be helpful.

http://www.comparecellular.ca/coverage-maps/

Answer (score 0):

These "signals" are types of wireless service which require a subscription to use, and compatible hardware with appropriate Sim card. You should contact wireless mobile data carriers in your area, often the same companies that provide cellular phone service.  What you are asking is very vague, unless you live in one of the most remote areas of the planet, at least one or more of those services is available in your area, whether it is compatible with your hardware is another story as there are various frequency and bands involved as well.